# Add custom URL to Image on a node

Tags: entities, media, uri

I'm using Drupal 7, and my nodes have an image and a weblink in seperate fields, The weblink is using the link module so not sure if that will complicate things here. (if so I could downgrade the link field to a text field)

anyway I'd like to create an `<A>` tag around my image whilst its being themed and I want the `href` or that `<a>` tag to point to the weblink url. Sounds like an easy thing to do hey... well I can't figure it out at all! so any help would be awesome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well your question, an alternative can be edit your image field ("Configure field" options) and select `Rewrite results > Rewrite the output of this field`. Here you can make lots of things with your image, for example add a link from other **previous** view field, over your image.

here one example to string included in the rewrite field:

```
<a href="[field_link_test]">[field_image_test]</a>
```

in this example [field_test_link] is a text field with the respective web address, and [field_image_test] is the field that comes with the image.

[image]

this image comes from Drupal 7, but this steps also are possible in Drupal 6

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the bold previous is completely correct, dont really understand how its working, but I've now removed the 'link' CCK as I couldn't get that to work, and now have a text field with the url in. I then use the image to lay down both the image link and the standard text link. bit weird but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is a module called [Link Image Field](http://drupal.org/project/linkimagefield)

> LinkImageField is a CCK module that allows you to specify the
>   hyperlink for images with a custom URL. The CCK ImageField allows
>   links from the image to the node or to the image itself, but not to a
>   user supplied link.
>
> Features Upload Image Title for the Image Alternative Text for the
>   Image URL to hyperlink the image Example Use: Your site supplies a
>   product image and description, but you want the image to link off-site
>   to an affiliated web store.

You can find a port to D7 [here](http://drupal.org/node/949588).

Answer (score 0):

Drawnword,

This is what worked for me:

Under Rewrite Results, scroll down until you see "Replacement Patterns".

Here is where you will see which tokens are available to include in the field.

Simply copy the tokens and paste them in the field above using the string provided by moon.watcher.

If you don't see your tokens, go back to the view, and rearrange the fields. In my case, I moved "Company Link" above "Company Logo".

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on Drupal 6 just ensure to put the alias in the link to page field you create in your content type, not the absolute path.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Any chance this will work in 7 - version OP is using?

Answer (score -1):

LinkImageField is a CCK module that allows you to specify the hyperlink for images with a custom URL. The CCK ImageField allows links from the image to the node or to the image itself, but not to a user supplied link :  http://drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Drupal answers.  It looks like your answer is duplicate to an already submitted answer for this question...