# How to link Images of one node to other node?

Tags: views

I've created a content type of image.

I am using a view to display the images on the homepage. I would like each of the three images to link to existing pages/nodes (not the nodes of images themselves).

I want to link images of node `a` to node `b` is that possible ?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: is there any relationship between the node and image? I can see from the post that the image is not with in the node you want to link it to. But is there any other ways it is related?

Comment: No, they are not related, that I am aware of. How would I go about "relating" them so that it's possible for me to hyperlink to the image/button?

Comment: you should add a entity reference from one node to the other. add a field of the type entity reference and choose the content type you want the entity to fill from. By the way should change the heading to read How instead of Low

Comment: What you mean by **Low to link Images?**

Comment: Ooops. Corrected. I meant how.

Comment: The user needs to customize this link or it is fixed somehow? Could you please explain about it?

Comment: if you need to specify the url maybe this module will help...i never use it thought http://drupal.org/project/linkimagefield in the other case maybe http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11994/add-custom-url-to-image-on-a-node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever way you look at it I would say that these images should be a field on the entity that they are linking to ( you are going to have a validation nightmare having a multiple image field and an entity reference field that can't be forced to have x number of values easily ). The easiest way to then render these would be to use the views module, create a block displaying fields and selecting he image field and clicking the box to link the image to the original piece of content. You can also have a filter to select only entities where this field is filled.

In reality though a better approach would be to create a menu ( this is what you are doing after all ) and put in the images using css.
example:

```
#block-system-main-menu li a {
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#block-system-main-menu li:nth-child(1) a {
  background-image:url('../images/icon_1.png');
}
#block-system-main-menu li:nth-child(2) a {
  background-image:url('../images/icon_2.png');
}
```

Comment: Thank you James. By using a menu, and adding the background image, I won't be able to click on the image though... Just the text. Is that right?

Comment: not at all... if you set the background image on the 'a' then the whole image will become the link, you may need to set the 'a' to be display:block so that you can set the width and height explicitly.

example is added to the answer so it can be read.

Answer (score 0):

If its in a view you can do something like this.

[image]

Or in the default content type display settings you can try 
[image]

Comment: I think he mentioned that the node in which the image is there is not the one which needs to be linked.

Comment: @MohammedShameem, an image to other node ? Come on...

Comment: (not the nodes of images themselves)

Comment: @MohammedShameem is there any algorithm to select which node to select ? like entity relation or something ?

Comment: Yes, I've got buttons on the homepage which I would like to link to pages within the site.

Comment: I am not sure @Nikhil M that is what I asked in the comment.

Comment: You are right Mohammed. That's what I mean.